# Necessary and sufficient conditions for $\alpha \wedge \beta = 0$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

given $\alpha \in \mathcal{A}^1(V)$ and $\beta \in \mathcal{A}^k(V)$, we can conclude that if there's a $\gamma \in \mathcal{A}^{k-1}(V)$ s.t. $\beta = \alpha \wedge \gamma$, then $\alpha \wedge \beta = \alpha \wedge \alpha \wedge \gamma  = 0$ since $\alpha$ is an odd valued tensor.

Now, given $\alpha \wedge \beta = 0$, how can I prove existence of $\gamma \in \mathcal{A}^{k-1}(V)$ s.t. $\beta = \alpha \wedge \gamma$?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to do it using basis elements for $\mathcal{A}^1(V)$ and $\mathcal{A}^k(V)$.

Comment: I obtained the following expression:

$$\alpha \wedge \beta = \frac{(1+k)!}{k!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+1}} Alt(\alpha \otimes \beta)(u_1,\dots,u_{k+1}) = 0$$

Is there some result for the alternator I can use in this case?

Comment: I mean, what would you have if $\alpha=v_1$ and $\beta=v_{i_1}\wedge ... \wedge v_{i_k}$.

Comment: Oh I see it now, thanks

Comment: one more thing, given that $\alpha \wedge \beta = v_1 \wedge v_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge v_{i_k} = 0$, does this imply $i_1 = 1$?

Comment: This implies that $i_j=1$ for some $j$.